# Setting OnClickListener to an ImageButton

Tags: java, android, xml

I have tried to set an `OnClickListener` to my `imageButton` but it didn't work. I've seen other questions about the topic but none of the ansqers work for me. Am I doing something wrong?

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public void Button()
    {
        View.OnClickListener listSet = new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        };
        boton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
        boton.setOnClickListener(listSet);
    }
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xxxx.xxx.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </WebView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gear"
        tools:background="@android:color/background_light"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show the error log please

Comment: are you sure to call Button() method ?

Answer (score 0):

Set clickable property of `ImageButton` to true

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_gear"
    tools:background="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Comment: This must be it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) ad.findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    boton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };);
```